# как вывести справочник?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

есть таблица users:

```
id :integer, autoincrement
name :string
gender_id :integer
```

есть таблица genders:

```
id :integer, autoincrement
gender_name :string
```

model User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :gender
end
```

model Gender:

```
class Gender < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :users
end
```

мне нужно в шаблоне вывести название пола. я пробую сделать так:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= user.name %></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><%= user.gender_id %></div>
<% end %>
```

в результате выводится цифра, но мне нужно чтобы вывелось название пола

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда выводишь название пола нужно писать вот так
`user.gender.gender_name`

`<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div class="col-xs-6"><%= user.name %></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"><%= user.gender.gender_name %></div>
<% end %>`